# Twilio videocall speed for non supporting region

Tags: twilio, region, twilio-video, videocall

I'm thinking to use Twilio to build a video communication platform.
The issue, that it'll be between MENA (Middle East and North Africa) & Europe regions.
While Twilio's infrastructure in Europe is robust, it appears that the MENA region is not directly supported (documentation does not list MENA as a covered region).
https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/tutorials/video-regions-and-global-low-latency#twilio-regions

Is there a way to empirically test or predict the quality of video calls using Twilio's services between these two regions before fully committing to their platform?